# How to calculate band gap alignment for different layers used in double perovskite solar cell?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, band-structure, perovskites, solar-cells

I want to compare the electronic bands (VBM and CBM) of a double perovskite material with other layer using like  transports both holes and electrons .I tried to calculate them, but the values I obtained are positive.I need help understanding how to calculate the positions of the VBM and conduction band (CBM) energy levels using Quantum Espresso. [image]

Comment: +1 Welcome to the community, I need to point out that it is not obvious for others what you have done and what you have already got in order for them to help you. Try to edit your quesiton, adding more details for the steps you have taken in the calculations and your basic input files, and the numerical values from the band structure calculation.

Comment: I don't understand your question completely. If you are asking about calculating the CBm and VBM positions from QE output for any material, I can write an answer. But I am not sure why you mentioned perovskite or layer information.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin , Usually I add nbnd and change  occupations from smearing to fixed in scf.in to specify VBM and CBM ,but it gives completel different values than those in figure for Cs2AgGaBr6 . is there another way that enables us to obtain the same ?

Comment: @KAMALASSIOUAN Did you check the occupations in the output file? If you know that the VBM is at the gamma point, then just check the occupation at gamma-point and note the highest energy value where occupation is 1. This is the VBM. If this is a direct band gap material, you can also note that next empty state energy value which is the CBm. The difference will give you the band gap. It is very much possible that you get VBM and CBm completely different than other calculation but the band gap should be comparable. Aslo, could you add a reference for the figure you added in the post?

Comment: @KAMALASSIOUAN I couldn't find the figure of your post in that paper.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin  I'm sorry, that it https://doi.org/10.1016/j.matchemphys.2022.126978